# "Preempting" less-used pages in high priority swap to lower priority swap

Tags: linux, debian, memory, swap, zram

Let's say I've got two swap partitions on my Linux machine. One is zram and a higher priority. The other is on disk and a lower priority. I prefer the zram swap because it's faster. As I understand it, based on the [swapon manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/swapon.2.html), the disk swap partition will not be used until the zram swap partition is exhausted.

Now, let's say I fill up the zram swap partition, so pages start getting sent to the disk one. But maybe some of the pages in the zram swap partition haven't been accessed in quite a while and it would make more sense to send those to disk and to have new pages take their place in the zram swap partition. After all, the zram should be faster, right?

Is there a way to do this?

For reference, I'm running Debian stretch. My kernel as printed by `uname -a` is `4.19.0-0.bpo.6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2~bpo9+1` (my company backported this), and I installed `zram-tools` at version `0.3.2.1-1` (I believe my coworker backported this from buster.)

Edit: I would accept a solution that works with kernel 5.x.

Comment: I'd have a method to do something similar to what's asked, but it appears to be available only since kernel 5.0. I guess you're not planning to upgrade to Debian 10 (and then use its buster-backport kernel) anytime soon?

Comment: @A.B I am, but I need to solve this problem first. It's hard to upgrade when the machine is overburdened all the time.

Comment: @A.B, how can you do this in 5.0?  The inability to do this has always been one of the downsides of using multiple swaps.  Frontswap was supposed to fix this but last I heard, it was abandoned and removed from the kernel.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would also appreciate an answer for kernel 5.x. I am going to edit my question to say as much, since we ended up just shutting these machines down and installing more memory while incurring some downtime during that period, and I'm no longer in a situation where I need to solve this problem first before we can upgrade to kernel 5.x.